# Get AD groups/ in AuthorizeAttribute, problems with sync and async

Tags: c#, asynchronous, graph, active-directory, authorization

For a MVC web application I have looked at a few ways to get the groups (and roles) of an Active Directory user.

*The template used is provided by Microsoft:

       https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/get-started (Microsoft Graph API, ASP.NET, Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, SDK sample)*

Microsoft doesn't return group claims even when enabled in the Application Manifest (apps.dev.microsoft.com). Apparently, groups won't return if user is in more than 5 groups. So I'm trying to get the groups and roles through the GetMemberObjects call.

I want to get the groups and roles of a user while in a custom AuthorizeAttribute class, but problems arise...

- The API calls in Microsoft Graph library are async. See example:
  `await client.Me.GetMemberObjects(true).Request().PostAsync()`
- The overridable methods in `AuthorizationAttribute` dont allow for async Tasks, which means I can't
  use `await` in a method like `OnAuthorization`, and using `async void` throws
  exceptions.
- `.Result` to attempt a blocking synced call doesn't work either since the context gets blocked--finished async Task can't get back on the main context, so deadlock occurs (infinite page loading). Same problem with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()`.
- Adding `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to all awaits doesn't work either since the Graph library has I assume built-in awaits that I can't configure to false.
- A custom class overriding ClaimsAuthenticationManage's ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate never gets accessed even though I've set up the web.config correctly. My plan was to get the groups and add them as Claims to the `ClaimsPrincipal` as soon as the latter gets populated, but this technique will probably fail too since the overridable method can't be changed to a return a `Task<ClaimsPrincipal>`.

Solutions?:

- Awaiting the async Task in a async method, the only place I can think of is
  in the controller. And this approach does work, but isn't good practice. Or so I've understood.
- Use ASP.NET vNext? Not sure about this but I'd like to stay on regular .NET.
- Use REST version of template. Actually, sync API calls work, as tested: `client.SendAsync(request).Result`, but problem is 
  still there when trying to get the Access Token. `IAuthProvider.GetUserAccessTokenAsync` is `async`, so `await` is again necessary in all subsequent parents since `.Result` will deadlock 100% of the time. So I'll be stuck again at `void OnAuthorization`.
- `Task.Run(()=>Method())` doesn't pass httpContext and is thread-unsafe. I plan to use this as a last resort if there is no other way.

So ideally I'd want to get the groups and roles of a user while in `OnAuthorization` or `AuthorizationCore`, to check for authorization on a certain controller action. But if there are other ways...suggestions? Thanks.